# Get only numbers (no dates) from an array and store them in order in a new array.Regex

Tags: html, arrays, regex

I''ve got an array with the next content:

```
Array(
[0] => <tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[1] => <tr><td>12/03/2015</td><td>10:12</td><td>98545 Column information</td><td>67659 Column information</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[2] => <tr><td>11/02/2015</td><td>12:40</td><td>59675 Column information</td><td>94859 Column information</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[3] => <tr><td>01/01/2015</td><td>20:12</td><td>69365 Column information</td><td>78464 Column information</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
)
```

How can I get the numbers stored in the third and fourth columns only?
What I want to do is store those numbers in an array to execute a script:

```
shell_exec("addnewgroups 12345 67899");
shell_exec("addnewgroups 98545 67659");
shell_exec("addnewgroups 59675 94859");
shell_exec("addnewgroups 69365 78464");
```

I'm trying with: preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $var);
But don't want to take the date and time numbers! :\

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Expected output:

```
12345, 67899 
98545, 67659 
59675, 94859 
69365, 78464
```

Or directly with the script before:

```
addnewgroups 12345 67899; 
addnewgroups 98545 67659; 
addnewgroups 59675 94859; 
addnewgroups 69365 78464;
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks a lot for your response!

The expected output is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex with preg_replace and then replace the match with `\1 \2`

```
.*?(\d+)\s.*?(\d+)\s.*
```

`(\d+)\s` captures one or more digits which was followed by a space. So it won't match any other number other than the one before a space. Replacing all the matched characters with the characters inside group index 1 (first number) and group index 2 (second number) will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK2oE3/1)

```
$re = "/.*?(\\d+)\\s.*?(\\d+)\\s.*/m";
$str = "<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>";
$subst = "$1, $2";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: thank you! worked like a charm! can you explain how it is working as good as it is? How the regex knows that date and time must be deleted?

Comment: If the string has a "-33" in his column is possible to get this value too in the same position?

$str = "<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 33</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>";

Output: 12345, 67899-33

Comment: it's deviated from the original question. Accept an answer and ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If it the structure is always the same (third and fourth columns) do it with this regex:

```
<td>.*?<td>.*?<td>(\d+).*<td>(\d+).*<td>
```

See it working in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB8bH5/1).

Comment: thanks a lot!! it's always nice to know other ways to do things!